# Can I use file.readline in a blocking manner? Am I doing this right?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a something that monitors a log file and adds a timestamp when it sees a complete line:

```
import sys

f = open(sys.argv[1])
if not f:
    print 'Failed to open %s' % sys.argv[1]

print sys.argv[1]

import time

try:
    while True:
        line = f.readline().replace('\n', '')
        if not line:
            continue
        print time.time(), line
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

f.close()
```

The check for line contents is there because, to my surprise, readlines does not block, but rather returns an empty string for the end of file immediately.

So then, for monitoring files, I have a few questions: Is there any way I can set this to block? I'm seeing empty strings in this loop, is there any chance they don't actually represent an end of line? Do files that are still opened for writing have end of line characters added to them?

Comment: Why is it surprising to you that readline() would not block? The far most common use case for readline() is reading and processing a static data file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Test file size with [`os.path.getsize`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.getsize) to see if there is a difference in the file
2. `f.readline` only if there is a difference in size
3. Every time you read call [`seek`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek) first to make sure you are actually reading the last line.
4. Use `f.readline()[0:-1]` to get rid of the trailing `\n` (thanks to rm for pointing out that `rstrip` might cause you problems)
5. Instead of running this loop *constantly*, test once a second and use [`sleep`](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.sleep) (Trust me, your computer will thank you)

Comment: `rstrip` will eat trailing spaces too, which might be a problem.

Comment: does tail -f have a way of adding a timestamp?

Comment: Hmm... I couldn't find one (granted, I've barely looked). Since that is a requirement, I removed the suggestion from the answer.

Answer (score 2):

you can open `tail` like program using subprocess and read its output which will block e.g. here is a quick python tail

```
import time
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
file_path = '/home/auniyal/src/main/app.log'
p = Popen(['tail', '-f', file_path], stdout=PIPE)

while True:
    line = p.stdout.readline()
    print time.time(),"Wow",line
```

Comment: Unhelpful on platforms lacking 'tail'.